# How do I change a background in movement in Unity?

Tags: unity, 2d

I'm developing a game and the background is moving and I wanna change to another image without losing the current speed of the movement.

File:

```
public class BackgroundMovement : MonoBehaviour

Material material;
Vector2 offset;
GameManager gameManager;
UIManager uiManager;
SpawnManager spawnManager;
public float speed = 0.3f;

private void Awake()
{
    material = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    gameManager = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>();
    uiManager = GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<UIManager>();
    spawnManager = GameObject.Find("SpawnManager").GetComponent<SpawnManager>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    offset = new Vector2(speed, 0);
    if(gameManager.gameOver == false)
    {
        GameSpeed();
        material.mainTextureOffset += offset * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

In Unity, I added to the material of the background a shader "unlit/transparent" and added the background in it. The object that this material is in, is a quad.

I tried to change creating a list of background images that I wanted on the game. One of the times I tried, I managed to change the background, but the image didn't move, only the first.

This is the inspector of the background.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show us: 1. How your background is built (there are dozens of ways to do this in Unity, so never assume that a stranger can just guess the one you used), 2. How you are moving your background now, 3. How you have tried changing your background image so far, 4. What specific unwanted symptoms do you observe when you do that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new at this.